# Powershell query to find users with emails containing .one attachments

Tags: azure, powershell

I'm trying to compile a powershell query which will return to me a list/file of all users who have received a .one attachment in their emails within the last 30 days, and if possible including the subject heading or date and time of the pertinent emails?

I've been trying a variety of commandlets such as `Search-mailbox`, `New-ComplianceSearch`, `New-MailboxSearch`, `Get-Mailbox` e.t.c. along with their associated parameters, but as some parameters aren't usable with other cmdlets, I'm not getting the results I need?

I'm hoping someone has an idea of how to achieve the above?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you provide the code that you tried

Answer (score 0):

**I tried to check the scenario in powershell.**

I have sent a mail attached with .one  format  to users in my azure ad with user type : member

[image]

[image]

**Check the below commands:**

```
  #install exchange online if not already present and connect
Install-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement
Import-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement
Update-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement

Connect-ExchangeOnline

$date = (Get-Date).AddDays(-2)

$log=Search-UnifiedAuditLog -StartDate $date -EndDate (Get-Date) -RecordType ExchangeItem -Operations Receive -ObjectIds "*.one" | Select-Object AuditData

$UsersWithOneAttachments = $log | Where-Object {$_.UserType -eq "Member"} | select * | Get-Unique

# Output the list of users
$UsersWithOneAttachments | Out-File -FilePath C:\Temp\UsersWithOnenoteAttached.csv
```

[image]